# array_merge dentro de un foreach

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de unir dos `arrays`, tengo lo siguiente:

En la variable `$ventas` tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
{
  "Mesa": [
    {
      "producto": "Mesa",
      "mes": "6",
      "total": "1"
    },
    {
      "producto_id": "0",
      "mes": "7",
      "total": "198"
    }
  ],
  "Silla": [
    {
      "producto_id": "Silla",
      "mes": "7",
      "total": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

También tengo otro `array` de meses:

```
$months = [
        '1' => 0, 
        '2' => 0, 
        '3' => 0, 
        '4' => 0,
        '5' => 0,
        '6' => 0,
        '7' => 0,
        '8' => 0,
        '9' => 0,
        '10' => 0, 
        '11' => 0,
        '12' => 0
    ];
```

Realicé  operaciones con `foreach`

```
foreach ($ventas as $indeOne => $venta) {
            foreach ($venta as $indexTwo => $value) {
                $array_1[$indeOne] = $value;
                foreach ($months as $indexTree => $month) {
                    if($indexTree == $value->mes){
                        $new[$indeOne][$indexTree] = $value->total;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Y esto me retorna lo siguiente:

```
{
  "Mesa": {
    "6": "1",
    "7": "198"
  },
  "Silla": {
    "7": "1"
  }
}
```

Lo que me dice que en el mes 6 tiene 1 venta y en el mes 198 así sucesivamente.

Pero el resultado que trato de obtener es lo siguiente:

```
{
  "Mesa": [
    {
      "1": 0,
      "2": 0,
      "3": 0,
      "4": 0,
      "5": 0,
      "6": 1,
      "7": 198,
      "8": 0,
      "9": 0,
      "10": 0,
      "11": 0,
      "12": 0,
    },
  ],
  "Silla": [
    {
      "1": 0,
      "2": 0,
      "3": 0,
      "4": 0,
      "5": 0,
      "6": 1,
      "7": 1,
      "8": 0,
      "9": 0,
      "10": 0,
      "11": 0,
      "12": 0,
    },
  ]
}}
```

Intenté meter un `array_merge()` dentro del foreach, pero me une mal.

Comment: De donde salio `-` y `Problemas Personales`?

Comment: Ya lo edité, gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que cambiar el orden de tus `foreach` y agregar un `elseif`.  Algo asi:

```
foreach ($ventas as $indeOne => $venta) {
    foreach ($months as $indexTree => $month) {
        foreach ($venta as $indexTwo => $value) {
            if($indexTree == $value->mes){
                $new[$indeOne][$indexTree] = $value->total;
            } elseif(!isset($new[$indeOne][$indexTree])) {
                $new[$indeOne][$indexTree] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo mejor es meter el array de meses entero y solo modificar por indice:

```
foreach ($ventas as $indeOne => $venta) {
        //Guardar llave con los meses
        $array_1[$indeOne][0] = $months;

        foreach ($venta as $indexTwo => $value) {
            //Llenar informacion de meses
             $array_1[$indeOne][0][$value['mes']] = $value['total']; 
        }
    }
```